# dyld: Library not loaded: React native

Tags: ios, react-native, cocoapods

I have developed the “SampleApp iOS framework” with swift development and using the below dependencies in our app:

```
pod 'Alamofire', '4.9.1'
pod 'JGProgressHUD', '2.0.3'
pod 'FirebaseCore', '6.4.0'
pod 'FirebaseMessaging', '4.1.10'
```

We can able to integrate the my “SampleApp framework” in the native swift application and it’s working file. But while integrated and run the same framework in the react native project. I am getting the below error

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/Alamofire.framework/Alamofire
  Referenced from: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/F50D-C62F291D4-8E6B-07B23BA0D-C6-B2E9-91AE/MyFirstApp.app/Frameworks/SampleApp.framework/SampleApp
  Reason: image not found
```

**Steps to be followed for integrating SDK in reaction native is below:**

1.Installed and run the node

2.sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local/lib/node_modules

3.react-native init MyFirstApp

4. iOS and android folders are generated.

5.I have opened the sample app framework and added my dependencies in pod install then run the pod install command.

6.Run the app in the Xcode Run option. App gets opened and getting the above alamo fire error

```
target 'FirstApp' do
  # Pods for FirstApp
  pod 'FBLazyVector', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/FBLazyVector"
  pod 'FBReactNativeSpec', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/FBReactNativeSpec"

  pod 'React-cxxreact', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/cxxreact'

  pod 'Yoga', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga', :modular_headers => true

  pod 'DoubleConversion', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/DoubleConversion.podspec'
  pod 'Folly', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/Folly.podspec'

pod 'Alamofire', '4.9.1'
pod 'JGProgressHUD', '2.0.3'
pod 'FirebaseCore', '6.4.0'
pod 'FirebaseMessaging', '4.1.10'
```

Note: **I have not used the Visual studio, I just open the iOS folder and do all changes same as native app. Is any other things needs to be added for react native project? I just wanted to compile the sample app without error.**

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Seems like need to add swift libraries within ios project.

Comment: I think so. Do you have an idea, where do I add the swift libraries? Right now I added in pod file.

Comment: Hello @HarikarthickK I am facing similar issue as Im introducing my own framework to iOS project (react-native). Do you manage to find the solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

To install a library in `react native` we have to follow this process.

suppose you want to install `keyboard` library,

```
npm i react-simple-keyboard
```

so we have to run to this command, it will add `react-simple-keyboard` `dependencies` in `package.json` which `react-native app` will use as a `reference`, next you need to install your pods

```
pod install
```

Comment: Thanks for answer @Tushar Pandey, I will try and let you know

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Is any other things needs to be added for react native project?

Comment: How to install "pod 'Alamofire', '4.9.1'"?

Comment: In react native we generally use fetch and axios for internet related tasks , explore it it will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding "use_frameworks!" in the Podfile to allow importing the framework dependencies ?